# When creating an active record in the datatbase, it is being created without the primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating an active record object like so:

```
shop = ShopifyShop.create(shopify_domain: shopDomain, primary_domain: shopObj.domain, shopify_token: token, user_id: userId) if !shop
```

When the an object with the same `primary_domain` is created, the record is not stored in the database and the object is created with no primary key

so when i do:

```
p shop
```

i get `#<ShopifyShop id: nil, shopify_domain: "***.myshopify.com", shopify_token: "***", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 45, primary_domain: "***.myshopify.com">`

I checked to see if it was related to constrain maybe but theres only a primary key constraint in the table, i am not sure what is causing this.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the validations you have for your shop caused your object to not be saved. `create` returns the object regardless of whether or not it was saved.

In order to investigate further:

```
shop.persisted?
# => false
shop.errors
# => will display errors of your object
```

Comment: Looks like there is a validation on the domain name that Shopifys gem adds when creating the model, i was so confused as to what was causing it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your object is simply invalid and therefore was not saved to database. That's why it has no `id`. You can check if there are any errors by:

```
shop.errors.any?
shop.errors.messages # => display errors
```

If you want to raise `RecordInvalid` error if validations fail, use `create!` instead of `create`.